# Calculate 3D distance based on change in intensity

Tags: image, matlab, 3d, processing, euclidean-distance

I have three sections (top, mid, bot) of grayscale images (3D). In each section, I have a point with coordinates (x,y) and intensity values [0-255]. The distance between each section is 20 pixels.
I created an illustration to show how those images were generated using a microscope:

Illustration
[image: Illustration.]

Illustration (side view): red line is the object of interest. Blue stars represents the dots which are visible in top, mid, bot section. The (x,y) coordinates of these dots are known. The length of the object remains the same but it can rotate in space - 'out of focus' (illustration shows a rotating line at time point 5). At time point 1, the red line is resting (in 2D image: 2 dots with a distance equal to the length of the object).

I want to estimate the x,y,z-coordinate of the end points (represents as stars) by using the changes in intensity, the knowledge about the length of the object and the information in the sections I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an example of images:

Bot section
[image: Bot section]

Mid section
[image: Mid section]

Top section
[image: Top section]

My 3D PSF data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qoyhWtLDD2fUy2zThYUgkYM3vMXxNh64/view?usp=sharing

Attempt so far:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrYre.png)

Comment: Do you know the `(x,y)`-coordinates of the points or do you need to find them?

Comment: I know the coordinates. Basically, I want to estimate the 'z' coordinate based on the intensity changes.

Comment: This is impossible withou knowing the relation between `z`-coordinate and intensity. It might help if you tell us how the images are generated.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I created a cartoon to illustrate the problem. I have time-lapse images which I thought can be useful as a reference (both dots are visible and share the same intensity profile) to estimate the z-coordinate.

Comment: Again, you do not provide the information how the images have been generated. Microscopy?

Comment: My apologies, yes these images were acquired from a microscope system. I have also the pixel size if this helps.

Comment: So you are asking how much "out of focus" is your object in the bot and top frames? Btw: I don't see two points in your mid-section image.

Comment: yes, that is correct. The length of the object remains the same but it can rotate in space. The example images I showed was from another time point. At the beginning (t1) the object (red line in the cartoon) is resting (in 2D image: 2 dots with a distance equal to the length of the object).  With time, it can rotate 'out of focus'. I want to estimate the x,y,z-coordinate of the end points (represents as stars) by using the changes in intensity and the knowledge about the length of the object. I hope I didn't confuse you. Thanks!

Comment: Would be a good idea to edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: Do you know the focal depth for each image? That is the best way to determine the z location -- it's given by the microscope stage. You do need to correct for the refraction index of the embedding medium if it's not air. -- In general, it is not possible to determine depth from signal attenuation. The attenuation depends on the optical properties of the material in between the focal point and the objective, as well as the properties of the objective, and you'd need to calibrate this (i.e. fit an exponential function to measured data to obtain the parameters of the attenuation.

Comment: Focal depth: I have a log-file generated by the microscope with Stage coordinates:   (e.g. -4623.130,+628.700,-35.689) for each image. I guess the last value is the focal depth. To correct the embedded medium and the dish thickness, I used oil with a refractive index of n=1.5340. I still don't understand mathematically/code-wise how to incorporate this information. Any hints (e.g. formula/code-snippets ) would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a formula that connects intensity and `z`-coordinate, and that formula is hard to find. Thus, it is best to calibrate the relation between intensity and `z` by recording `z`-stacks of a known object with known properties. In case of fluorescence microscopy, things like bleaching etc.pp. have to be considered, too. Maybe [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) helps.

Comment: The microscope system I used is already calibrated with a PSF. I tried to find an article/formula etc. that relates intensity and z-coordinates but couldn't find a solution. That's why I created this post.

Comment: This is very helpful information. A simplistic attempt would be: 1. Get the indices of the (x,y)-coordinates of the PSF Let's assume they are `(x0, y0)`. 2. Plot the PSF data through the center along `z`: `plot(1:size(psf,3), psf(x0, y0, :))`. Look at that data. It often looks like a gaussian distribution. If it looks like that, 3. fit a gaussian distribution to it to find the corresponding parameters. 4. Use the corresponding formula to compute the `z`-positions from the intensity (note that due to the typical symmetry of the PSF, there might be two corresponmding `z`-coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the correct approach would be to record three images with slightly different `z`-coordinates for your **bot** and your **top** frame, then do a 3D-deconvolution (using [Richardson-Lucy](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/deconvlucy.html) or whatever algorithm).

However, a more simple approach would be as I have outlined in my comment. If you use the data for a publication, I strongly recommend to emphasize that this is just an estimation and to include the steps how you have done it.

I'd suggest the following procedure:

Since I do not have your PSF-data, I fake some by estimating the PSF as a 3D-Gaussiamn. Of course, this is a strong simplification, but you should be able to get the idea behind it.

First, fit a Gaussian to the PSF along `z`:

```
[xg, yg, zg] = meshgrid(-32:32, -32:32, -32:32);

rg = sqrt(xg.^2+yg.^2);

psf = exp(-(rg/8).^2) .* exp(-(zg/16).^2);


% add some noise to make it a bit more realistic

psf = psf + randn(size(psf)) * 0.05;
% view psf:

% 
subplot(1,3,1);
s = slice(xg,yg,zg, psf, 0,0,[]);
title('faked PSF');
for i=1:2
    s(i).EdgeColor = 'none';
end

% data along z through PSF's center

z = reshape(psf(33,33,:),[65,1]);
subplot(1,3,2);
plot(-32:32, z);
title('PSF along z');

% Fit the data

% Generate a function for a gaussian distibution plus some background

gauss_d = @(x0, sigma, bg, x)exp(-1*((x-x0)/(sigma)).^2)+bg;

ft = fit ((-32:32)', z, gauss_d, ...
    'Start', [0 16 0] ... % You may find proper start points by looking at your data
);

subplot(1,3,3);
plot(-32:32, z, '.');
hold on;
plot(-32:.1:32, feval(ft, -32:.1:32), 'r-'); 
title('fit to z-profile');
```

[image]

The function that relates the intensity `I` to the `z`-coordinate is

```
gauss_d = @(x0, sigma, bg, x)exp(-1*((x-x0)/(sigma)).^2)+bg;
```

You can re-arrange this formula for `x`. Due to the square root, there are two possibilities:

```
% now make a function that returns the z-coordinate from the intensity
% value:

zfromI = @(I)ft.sigma * sqrt(-1*log(I-ft.bg))+ft.x0;
zfromI2= @(I)ft.sigma * -sqrt(-1*log(I-ft.bg))+ft.x0;
```

Note that the PSF I have faked is normalized to have one as its maximum value. If your PSF data is not normalized, you can divide the data by its maximum.

Now, you can use `zfromI` or `zfromI2` to get the `z`-coordinate for your intensity. Again, `I` should be normalized, that is the fraction of the intensity to the intensity of your reference spot:

```
zfromI(.7)

ans =

    9.5469

>> zfromI2(.7)

ans =

   -9.4644
```

Note that due to the random noise I have added, your results might look slightly different.

Comment: Firrst of all, many thanks for your help. I really appreciate your toy example and I think I understand the steps you suggested. I converted the otf-file (PSF) to an Tiff which I have attached to the original post. I should have mentioned that the images were taken from a deconvolution microscope system. I guess I don't have to use an additional 3D deconvolution, right? Since the PSF (see image) is symmetric, I can simply use either one.

Comment: If the data in your images is already deconvolved, I'd suggest to look for a way to  find out the `z`-coordinate in your decon-software (maybe as a depth-color coded image or similar). I would not hesitate to call the software support. Your attached PSF-image is not 3D (might have been converted during the upload), and thus I cannot use it for my simple approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was very useful. I am in touch with the Software company and will update you as soon as I have further information.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I had to acquire a new PSF to get the 3D information. I have attached the file in the initial post. I followed your example but after visual inspection, the estimated coordinate seems not correct. I used a Spline to fit the z-profile because my PSF is far from Gaussian. Could you please have a look at my updated PSF data? Many thanks.